# How can I purge all post revisions except the latest 5?

Tags: revisions

I know I can use `define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 5);` to limit future post revisions to 5, but how would I go about purging all *existing* revisions except the latest 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this plugin that lets you specify how many revisions you wish to keep:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/rvg-optimize-database/

Answer (score 1):

Please take database backup and run a below MYSQL query and check is this helpful:

DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "revision" AND ID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'revision' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5)

Comment: Older versions of MySQL do not support using "limit" in subqueries. You might want to try this instead. `SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "revision" AND ID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'revision' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5) rev);`

Comment: You're correct - my version of mysql did not allow me to use the suggestion you're replying to. I ended up using your suggestion (and replacing the first `SELECT` with `DELETE`, although I think it ended up deleting them all because I don't see any revisions anymore. I did have a backup though.

Answer (score 0):

To limit the number of revision saved in the future, you can use

```
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 5 );
```

Every time you'll save a post, a maximum number of `5` revisions will be kept in the database and all the older ones will be removed.

This will, however, remove them only when saving the posts, so you may want to manually use @Yash solution the first time if you really have a huge dataset.